# How to vertically expand container widget in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, widget, flutter-layout

trying to expand `Expanded` or `Container` **vertically** to match its **height** with `Row` widget **height**, here is my code

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: ()=> onDepartClicked(),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Card(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 8,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(department.name,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset("assets/images/feedback.png", width: 20, height: 20,),
                            SizedBox(width: 4,),
                            Text(department.phone),
                            SizedBox(width: 16,),
                            Image.asset("assets/images/feedback.png", width: 20, height: 20,),
                            SizedBox(width: 4,),
                            Text(department.type),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),child: Divider(height: 0.3, color: Colors.grey,)),
                      Container(
                        child: Text(department.description,
                          maxLines: 3,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 40,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(4), bottomRight: Radius.circular(4))
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset("assets/images/feedback.png",
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to expand this block in the above code (second child of the `Row`):

```
Container(
            width: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(4), bottomRight: Radius.circular(4))
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset("assets/images/feedback.png",
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

I want to achieve this view with blue area expanded vertically in parent
[image]

Comment: Can You upload the UI you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @NoobN3rd screenshot upload. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit after more clarification on the question:**

The idea behind the code below is like the [This Image](https://app.diagrams.net?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Untitled%20Diagram.drawio#R5ZhNj5swEIZ%2FDcdWgPnKsUDSHhqpUg5t9%2BbA8LFrcOSYJPTX14AJYcNGqRRASskhntdjYz8zjAUK8rLTV4Z3yZqGQBRdDU8K8hVd18yFJf4qpWwUx9EbIWZpKJ06YZP%2BASmqUi3SEPY9R04p4emuLwY0zyHgPQ0zRo99t4iS%2Fl13OIYrYRNgcq3%2BTEOeyF2Yaqd%2FgzRO2jtrquzJcOsshX2CQ3q8kNBSQR6jlDet7OQBqeC1XJpxqw96zwtjkPN7Bry8vaxff7irIveplh2iNfWXn%2BQsB0wKuWG5WF62BBgt8hCqSVQFucck5bDZ4aDqPYqYCy3hGRGWJppRSohHCWX1WBRicKJA6HvO6Btc9FiBA9tI9MgFAONw%2BnBn2pmXSDSgGXBWChc54Iy4PAehsY9dxFCrJZfRsqSIZZbE57k7kKIhWf4LV3TFEUKRWNKkjCc0pjkmy051%2B6Q7n%2B%2BU7iTfV%2BC8lE8JLjjt0xe8WPmrGv%2FZbM3fcrra8E89q5RWs9ZqgbcjIPZDCxbAjY3L%2FOGYxcBv%2BJnDEWVAME8P%2FXU8PDr6uFkfOQEEg1m%2FdUzDVKfLet2YNOvRM1YThOavJsYc1eSBVcG4sypo6nBopikLxshlwax%2Bg%2BlbX9UImvMLvbmmS%2BuJy4U5Lm%2FQQhPsId4Ly0bYmpmrMRZWe%2BQ0jsAaPt1Ce7FVRzrdkD03VucZDzfTnP1wW%2FxPVXeI98RVt43uc5Xdu8GOVh%2B0kd%2BlPf%2BL7i6HuOq%2BbdV1910iR%2FU1Eu%2FF7LxHfotbrSzLRUO8VVXzXW9%2B3pr%2BGN7C7D5D1X0XH%2FPQ8i8%3D).

Left child of the row contains a column, the column has 3 children.

The first child of the column is the title, second one is a Row of phone and type and the last one is the description.

For "phone" and "type" you can use `ListTile` but you should put them on something like `Flexible` or define size for them.

I deinded a `Listview` and put 10 card inside it.

Here is the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _card();
          },
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 10,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _card() {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              flex: 5,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'UBIT',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.message),
                      SizedBox(width: 4),
                      Text('+09210000000'),
                      SizedBox(width: 16),
                      Icon(Icons.message),
                      SizedBox(width: 4),
                      Text('Science'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(),
                  Text(
                    'Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für ' +
                        'die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ' +
                        'ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text' +
                        ' seit 1500',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.message,
                size: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is working solution, but it would be great if it will be without specific height of main container

Comment: If you use it besides other widgets, doesn't it work? it tries to fit. because I used it as an only widget in `body` I wanted to make some limitation.

Comment: no its not working properly if I remove height from main container and use it in listview

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Container in a SizedBox with height:double.infinity to make it take all the available space, in your case the height of the row.

```
Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
               height:double.infinity,
               child:Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     color: Colors.blue,
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(4), bottomRight: Radius.circular(4))
                     ),
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/feedback.png", width: 20, height: 20, fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,),
                  ),
              ),
          )
```

Comment: not working.. throwing this error " BoxConstraints forces an infinite height. "

Comment: Whats the parent of your card?

Comment: InkWell -> Container -> Card